# Как научится низкоуровневому программированию под linux

Tags: linux, c, ядро

Изучаю язык С и учусь работать в Linux. Далее планирую заняться низкоуровневым программированием под Linux, в частности работой с ядром Linux. Есть книги по ядру, планирую их изучать, но что делать дальше мне неясно. Пожалуйста посоветуйте направление развития для данной области. И какие есть специализации в данной области? Насколько знаю это - написание драйверов, тестирование; вроде и все...

Answer (score 2):

[[@1z0](/users/24495/1z0)](/users/24495/1z0), в качестве работы за которую платят деньги?

--

Что же касается ответа на заголовок вопроса, то я бы посоветовал начать с чтения файлов в /usr/include и самостоятельного обдумывания, как бы Вы сами это реализовали.

**Обновление**

Большинство из них -- к устройству ядра действительно отношения не имеют.

Однако, обратите внимание -- низкоуровневое программирование в Linux это по большей части не программирование ядра, а программирование с использованием libc (и опосредовано ядра).

По поводу, непосредственно ядра. Почитайте конечно книжки, например, Роберт Лав "Linux. Системное программирование" и "Разработка ядра Linux"
и потом потренируйтесь. Скачайте исходники, посмотрите как люди пишут, попробуйте что-нибудь свое придумать и добавить.

**Обновление 2**

Вот небольшой список сайтов:

https://www.kernel.org/    наверняка известен Вам, там http://vger.kernel.org/ -- можете подписаться на e-mail рассылку -- место, где размещают важные сообщения и члены сообщества ведут разработку.

http://lwn.net/  новости Linux

http://kernelnewbies.org/  Linux Kernel Newbies

читайте, изучайте.

Comment: А какое отношение имеют эти файлы к kernel?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Да, наверно я неправильно сформулировал заголовок - все таки меня больше интересует ядро, а не низкоуровневое программирование...
И по книгам, собираюсь их читать и по ним работать, но что дальше делать?

Comment: Обновил ответ